# how to use If condition in Handlebar HBs engine

Tags: node.js, express, syntax-error, handlebars.js

### i have useing this peace of code and facing an error as I mentioned below
Parse error on line 26:
...       {{#if (error !="")}}
<

Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'INVALID'

How to solve this ?

code I use in hbs is

```
       {{#if (error !="")}}  
    <div
      class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show"
      role="alert"
    >
      <strong> Error </strong>
      {{error}}
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn-close"
        data-bs-dismiss="alert"
        aria-label="Close"
      ></button>
    </div>

    {{/if}}
```

Comment: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#if ~ You can use the if helper to conditionally render a block. If its argument returns false, undefined, null, "", 0, or [], Handlebars will not render the block. `{{#if (error !="")}}` should be `{{#if error}}`

Comment: can you help ma to write the code,I'm beginner and I cant understood

Comment: as said, replace `{{#if (error !="")}}` with `{{#if error}}`

Comment: i tried but not work.

Comment: Will you help ma to rewrite above code ....